# What is the function to return the name/address of a cell or range (Spreadsheet)?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I could not find the function that returns the name of the cell referenced. For example, `=SOMETHING(A5)` that will return `A5` as string.

So that, I can write `="For more information, see " & SOMETHING(F50) & "."` in a cell and the cell will read `For more information, see F50.`, and then, when I **move** the F50 cell, the text will also change.

So, what is that `SOMETHING`?

If it works for Google Spreadsheet it's the best, but if you are not familiar with Google Spreadsheet, OpenOffice Calc and MS Excel solutions are most probably compatible too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel you can use the [ADDRESS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052089831033.aspx) function.

Comment: Google Docs has `address` too: https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=82712#address

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, =ADDRESS( ROW(F50), COLUMN(F50), 4 ) returns what I want :)
The bad thing is I need to write the cell reference twice. Any better way?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you can also use the **CELL** function.

```
="For more information, see " & CELL("address",F50) & "."
```

will return

```
For more information, see $F$50.
```

---

An alternate is to create a hyperlink to the location based on the **CELL** function.  It will be easier for the end user, but the formula is more complex.

```
=HYPERLINK((MID(CELL("filename",F50),4,255)&"!"&CELL("address",F50)),"For more information click here.")
```

this will return

```
For more information click here.
```

and when it is clicked on, the cell specified will be selected.